# Dynamically replacing HTML with getJSON by click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getjson

I have a webpage that displays a news story in the main body, and has a side navigation bars where four other stories are listed. I am trying to use json files to swap out the html text in the main body. Each story has it's own json file. Here is my current javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#nav_list a").click(function(evt) {
    buildName = "../json_files/" + $(this).attr("title") + ".json";
    alert(buildName);
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";

    $.getJSON(buildName, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            $.each(this, function(key, value) {
                $("#main").append(
                    "<h1>" + value.title + "</h2>" +
                    "<img src='" + value.image + "'>" +
                    "<h2>" + value.month + "<br>" + value.speaker + "</h2>" +
                    "<p>" + value.text + "</p>";
                );
            }); // inner each       
        }); // outer each
    )}; // end of getJSON           

}); // end click    

}); // end ready
```

Notes:

1. The alert(buildName) is for my own testing.
2. The next line (w. the innerHTML) should clear the current body content.
   ** NOTE: This works if I have the $.getJSON method commented out! Otherwise both this and my alert() are entirely ignored.
3. Because each store has it's own json file, I questioned the necessity of the muliple $.each methods within the getJSON. It didn't make a difference (the format I have below is from my textbook and has worked on a single json file with multiple entries).

I even tried not clearing the initial innerHTML and overwriting, but I may have had some syntax wrong. Here is that attempt:

```
        $.getJSON(buildName, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $("#main").append(
                    ("#main h1").innerHTML.replace("<h1>" + value.title + "</h2>");
                    ("#main img").innerHTML.replace("<img src='" + value.image + "'>");
                    ("#main h2").innerHTML.replace("<h2>" + value.month + "<br>" + value.speaker + "</h2>");
                    ("#main p").innerHTML.replace("<p>" + value.text + "</p>");
                )
            }); // endeach
    )}; // end of getJSON
```

What do you guys think? I am absolutely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semi-colon at the end inside your .append(). Otherwise, I'm not sure. I wanted to comment this instead of answering but I lack the reputation. With your second attempt, those replace calls shouldn't be made inside the .append(). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I removed the semi-colon, no dice on that being the resolution though. I also tried eliminating the outside append(), with and without dual each statements (if that even makes sense). Either way, issue remains.

Comment: As far as steps go to isolate the issue, comment out the insides of your getJSON and see if you can get a simple alert thrown from inside there. If that's working, see if you can access the JSON data (fill the alert with the data). Is your developer console giving you any errors or warnings?

Comment: Good idea, Adam. Thank you. I commented everything after the initial .getJSON and added an alert("hello"). It didn't work. I'm not seeing any errors or warnings.

Comment: If that's the case your problem is likely one of two things: 1. the request is returning something other than 200 (OK), likely a 404 (not found) or 500 (internal server error), or 2. the requested file is not a valid JSON file. You can validate your JSON data at jsonlint.com. I've looked around and people recommend using Chrome's Resource Tab (in the devtools) to see the JSON request and response firing to get a better understanding of the issue

Comment: Whoa .. okay, I just clicked back on my program in Aptana to copy over my JSON file (which should all be fine, this is sample code for a class) and there was a pop-up console message. It's too long to leave in a comment, but much of it seems repetitive (to be honest, I've ignored any console pop-ups in the past and haven't had issues:

1490923650092 addons.xpi WARN Ignoring missing add-on in C:\Program Files\Trend Micro\AMSP\module\20013\FxExt\firefoxextension

Comment: Didn't mean to hit send. A couple more (A) [Parent 10072] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 345. (B) 490988614528 Sync.ErrorHandler ERROR Sync encountered a login error (C) console.error: downloadhelper: 
  Message: TypeError: Type does not implements method: patch@diffpatcher#qsajbrb5q0g

Comment: Not sure what to say. Those errors seem to take issue with your browser and it's hard to say if it's having an effect on how your code is performing.

Comment: Is there a way I can call/trigger a set of code based off of the completion of this line: document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";

Comment: Yeah. innerHTML = doStuff(); function doStuff(){ return "stuff" //insert code here}

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be your json path that you construct.

Try using a standard path "../file.json" or "file.json" to check if you have the result you want or if the `$`.getJSON() is still ignored.

About the other errors: What is  your devel. environment?

I also noticed that you have a bracket mismatched in your append  function at the title part. So,
`"<h1>" + value.title + "</h2>" +`
would have to be changed to..

```
"<h1>" + value.title + "</h1>" +
```

Comment: Same results. I have tried both entering the path manually (../json_files/file.json) and moving a file into the root directory, "file.json". I commented mostly everything out here too except for the line to clear the inner HTML of the main element. Really odd behavior here. I have a very similar program and it all works fine, except for it is one json file instead of multiple, and in the root directory.

I am using Aptana Studio 3, build 3.6.1.2014. I'm not terribly concerned about those errors.

Comment: Is it possible that you have an issue wiring your event? Did you try using a :button selector to your click event instead of your navigation bar link?

Answer (score 0):

I have re-created a sample of your site and it all seems to run fine using your code and .json files.

I just needed to modify the code as shown below. In this case, if you have a heading it will also clear the heading in your website.

```
<!--json  retrieve script starts here -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(":button").click(function() {
buildName = "../json_files/" + $(this).attr("title") + ".json";
alert(buildName);
//$("#main").empty();
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";

$.getJSON(buildName, function(data){
//$.each(data, function() {
  //  $.each(data, function(key, value){
     $("#main").append(
          "<h1>" + data.title + "</h2>" +
          "<img src='" + data.image + "'>" +
          "<h2>" + data.month + "<br>" + data.speaker + "</h2>" +
          "<p>" + data.text +"</p>"
   );
// });
//});
});
 });
});
</script>
<!--json script end here -->
```

NOTE: I have swapped the link with button to wire the event for this example.

You can also use multiple file entries in a single .json file in the format shown below:

```
{
"story1":"/jsonfile1.json",
"story2":"/jsonfile2.json",
"story3":"/jsonfile3.json"
}
```

which you would then parse with an `$.each(data,function(key,value)` where value would be the filename to be requested via `$.getJSON` so you can have multiple entries handled by a single file.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few syntax errors - a parenthesis and curley bracket out of order, misplaced semi-colon, things of the like. The logic was correct.

Thanks all for the replies!